# Stroke not applied to React-Icons

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-icons

**Stroke or Text nothing is applied with react-icons**

```js
 <AiOutlineArrowLeft
              className="cursor-pointer text-xl text-orange-800 stroke-4"
              onClick={(e) => handleBurger(e)}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because tailwind only has `stroke-0`,`stroke-1` and `stroke-2` classes defined  whereas you had defined `stroke-4`.

Find more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/stroke-width#setting-the-stroke-width)